# Keras custom metrics R2 vs SKlearn R2

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, statistics

I have implemented the simple custom metrics for R2 score, since i am dealing with a regression task.

```
def r_2_score(y_true, y_pred):
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
    RSS =  K.sum(K.square( y_true- y_pred ))
    TSS = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
    return ( 1. - RSS/(TSS) )
```

Then i compared results with this method and the one present in sklearn library

```
print(sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test_data,model.predict(x=x_test_data)))

model.evaluate(x=x_test_data, y=y_test_data)
```

but they gave me completely different results

0.3706 with sklearn R2 method

0.8812 with keras custom metric

what could be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure. May be the part `return ( 1. - RSS/(TSS) )` is not well written and you should write `return ( 1. - (RSS/TSS) )` instead.